# Determine whether certain nodes on a graph are directly connected

Tags: javascript, algorithm, data-structures, graph, graph-traversal

How can I determine whether selected nodes on a graph are directly connected?

I think, I need to calculate paths for each selected node to all of the other selected nodes. Then, when I have the path, I have to check whether path contains *only* selected nodes.

In the code, all I have is a notion of `nodes` and `edges`, like this:

```js
const nodes = [
  { id: "A" },
  { id: "B" },
  { id: "C" },
  { id: "D" },
  { id: "E" },
  { id: "F" },
];

const edges = [
  { target: "A", source: "B" },
  { target: "B", source: "C" },
  { target: "C", source: "D" },
  { target: "D", source: "E" },
  { target: "E", source: "F" },
];
```

Examples:

Good selection:

[image]

Bad selection:

[image]

Is there some algorithm for checking that? Are you aware of some npm packages in case of JavaScript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Possible solution

1. Transform the current directed graph into an undirected graph (so for each pair `(source, target)`, `(target, source)`should be added to `edges` too), as we are not interested in whether A reaches B or B reaches A, but instead we are trying to see whether they are connected
2. Run a **graph traversal algorithm** ([Depth First Search (DFS) or Breadth First Search (BFS)](https://codeburst.io/implementing-dfs-and-bfs-using-javascript-5034f3cee9a1) from *any* selected node on the undirected graph you've just created. If all selected nodes can be reached, return `true`, otherwise return `false`

#### Notes

- It does not matter from which `selected node` you run the DFS/BFS from as long as the graph is undirected. Therefore, it is important to run DFS/BFS **only once** to keep `O(1)` time complexity. Running DFS/BFS from *all* selected nodes will result in `O(N)` time complexity, where `N = # of nodes`, and would also provide a correct result, but would introduce redundant graph traversals.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. That doesn't sound like something easy to do, but I will comeback to it and will try to code it. Thanks again!